# Linq to SQL: combine two columns to make a readonly custom column

Tags: linq-to-sql

Basically, it's the simple scenario of needing to populate a dropdown with LastName, FirstName by combining the two columns in the entity to FullName.  I'd like it to live in the entity so I can grab it whenever I find a use for it.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a partial class that has the FullName property. Have a look at the designer file for your data context classes for the namespace and partial classname to use.

```
namespace your.namespace {

  public partial class yourclassname {
      public string FullName {
          get { return string.format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: I believe this gave me some "not an updateable SQL something something" error when I tried this initially?  I'll have to check again but it there's some trick to it?

Comment: ah sweet - that worked.  I swear I tried that before but I must have had some minor difference in mine.  thanks!!!

Comment: Only problem I have had is for a stored procedure result object....it will throw an error on those....something about a property without a setter. I believe you can "trick" those by decorating the partial class with a [Table] attribute.