# SQL/C# MVC: Order over multiple fields

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have records that have "FirstName" and "LastName" for individuals, and "CompanyName" for companies. Both records reside in one single table, and I know whether it's a company or an individual through an IsCompany Bit field in my table.

The problem I face now is that I need to show those in one **ordered** grid, in the form:

```
Last Name, First Name

or (if it's a company)

Company Name
```

It's not a "real" grid, its merely a table that is rendered server side. How do I order this (via SQL/LINQ?) so that I get it ordered correctly, e.g.:

```
Fizz, Marc                (INDIVIDUAL)
Fields, Jonathan          (INDIVIDUAL)
Futile Resistance Inc.    (COMPANY)
Fyat, Abel                (INDIVIDUAL)
```

I appreciate your help folks.... Having a tough time with this right now :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN IsCompany = 1 THEN Company
    ELSE LastName + ', ' + FirstName END AS DisplayName
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY DisplayName
```

Comment: @Alex: It's server side SQL. Not sure on the method to call it from LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to Linq to SQL?  If so, create a partial class with a DisplayName property built off of the suggested FirstName, LastName, IsCompany and Company logic. You will want to use the namespace and partial class name as found in the designer file. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506046/linq-to-sql-combine-two-columns-to-make-a-readonly-custom-column) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Linq2Sql

```
var results = datacontext.TableName.OrderBy(a => a.IsCompany ? a.CompanyName : a.LastName + ", " a.FirstName);
```

Comment: But this would require me to return ALL records from the database into the application layer first? I'm trying to still only get the records I need from MSSQL